# Display <div> when items are in Woocommerce cart but hide when empty

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I hope you can help me. I would like to display a div in a notification bar whenever there is an item (or items) in the Woocommerce cart but hide it if the cart is empty.

All I'm finding are ways to display a cart icon in the menu. But I don't want a cart icon, nor do I want it in the menu, and I definitely only want it to display if there's something in the cart.

I'm open to a CSS solution, script, or adding to function.php

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Where is this / how do you want to implement this - as PHP in a template, or CSS applied to the page, or something else?

Comment: You probably want `WC()->cart->is_empty()`, or `$cart->is_empty()` depending on where you are testing that and whether you have `$cart` to hand..

Comment: Thanks, @Rup. I updated my question. I hope it helps. I appreciate your help.